# How to keep the latest commit but revert its changes

Tags: git

I need to revert the code changes of latest commit, but at the same time keep the commit ID, is it possible?

I tried git reset but it will remove the commit id as well.

Below are the pseudo steps:

let's say gerrit G1 in branch B1 of project P1 having latest, second latest commits G1, G2...so on. What I am trying here:

```
git clone P1 in local
git checkout B1
git cherrypick G1
revert the G1 change
Keep the commit ID of G1
git commit --amend to B1
```

Comment: `git revert HEAD` will create a new commit that undoes the changes. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, you can´t. A commit ID is dependent on (among other things) content of the files in the commit so if you change a bit from a file, you won't be able to get the same commit ID with that.

Comment: @Ry-, no. I have updated pseudo steps in question.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the contents of a commit without changing its hash/id is not possible.

As per https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F:

> Everything in Git is checksummed before it is stored and is then referred to by that checksum. This means it’s impossible to change the contents of any file or directory without Git knowing about it. This functionality is built into Git at the lowest levels and is integral to its philosophy.

Ensuring that the same commit hash points to the exact same state of a repository is one of the core integrity guarantees that git provides.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `git revert HEAD` command.

Go and have a look at the doc to see if this is really what you want.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Comment: This will not work for OP as they wish to preserve their commit id, which is impossible as it is calculated off of the tree object hash. This is the correct answer for the sane dev who opts to preserve git history. An ameliorating commit will be created.